# How to show 0 and 1 onclick same button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info hold" title="Hold"><i class="icon-control-pause"></i></a>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".hold").click(function(){
            alert('1');
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have a button Now, what I want when I click on the first time it alerts `1` and when I click on the second time it shows `0`. I have no idea about how can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: What about clicking it the third time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can maintain one variable as a flag:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var flag = true;
  $(".hold").click(function(){
    if(flag){
      alert('1');
      flag = false;
    }
    else{
      alert('0');
      flag = true;
    } 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info hold" title="Hold"><i class="icon-control-pause">Test</i></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean like this? Just use a variable to keep track of the current state:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var alertNumber = 1;
  $(".hold").click(function() {
    alert(alertNumber);
    alertNumber = 1 - alertNumber;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><button class="hold">Click me!</button></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var clickedTimes = 0;
$(".hold").click(function(){
  clickedTimes++;
  alert(clickedTimes % 2 == 0 ? '1' : '0');
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info hold" title="Hold"><i class="icon-control-pause"></i>Test</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show `0` only on the second click, then then keep count of the clicks and check if the user has clicked twice or not.

```js
var clickCount = 0;
$(".hold").click(function(){
  clickCount++;
  var alertZeroOnlyOnTheSecondClick = clickCount == 2 ? '0' : '1'
  alert(alertZeroOnlyOnTheSecondClick);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info hold" title="Hold"><i class="icon-control-pause"></i>Test</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will show either `0` or `1` depending on the times you click.

```
var _click = 0;
$('.hold').on('click', function() {
    _click = _click == 0 ? 1 : 0;
    alert(_click);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`Use logical not operator so as to toggle between true and false`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    let text = false;

    $('.hold').click(function() {
        text =  !text;
        alert(Number(text));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info hold" title="Hold"><i class="icon-control-pause"></i>Click Me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will get the job done for you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var alertNumber = false;
  $(".hold").click(function() {
    alertNumber === true ? alert(1) : alert(0);
    alertNumber = !alertNumber; // alertNumber is now the opposite of what it was.
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var msg = 0;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".hold").click(function(){
            alert((++msg) % 2);
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info hold" title="Hold"><i class="icon-control-pause">Toggle Alert</i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I’d do it with solution **val = !val**, but for the concrete case there’s another idea:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info hold" title="Hold"><i class="icon-control-pause"></i></a>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var i = 1;
        $(".hold").click(function(){
            alert( i );
            i—-;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another way using data attribute. Regards

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".hold").click(function(){
    alert($(this).data('clicked'));
    $(this).data('clicked', 
    $(this).data('clicked')=='0' ? '1' : '0')
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-clicked="0" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info hold" title="Hold"><i class="icon-control-pause">Toggle Alert</i> </a>
```